# Удалить разделитель строки в полученной замене

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Замена строки заключается в тег. Но вместе с разделителем. Как удалить?

```
 $str = "text | text | text |";

 preg_replace("/(.+?(?:\|))/uis", "<p>$1</p>", $str);
```

Comment: Каждое слово или вся строка в тег оборачивается?

Comment: `([^\s\|]+)`...

Comment: Каждое слово,  ([^\s\|]+) немного подходит, но работает только в первом вхождении

Comment: Имел в виду при таком варианте /(.+?[^\|]+)/

Answer (score 0):

Рациональное решение на php:

```
<?php
$str = "text | text | text |";
$str_new = str_replace(" |", "", "<p>$str</p>");
echo $str_new;
?>
```